# How can i open correct ports on windows firewall for apache instead of using all?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, port, windows-firewall

I installed an Apache2 (8085 and 8086 ports) in a fresh windows 2008 R2 installation. But i found a problem opening ports. I opened the firewall for the program httpd.exe (full and correct path) for the TCP ports already mentioned and i can't access it, but when i open all ports it works. am i missing something?

I mean accessing from Lan.

Thanks for all of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security'
2. Go to 'Inbound Rules'
3. 'New Rule...'
4. 'Port'
5. 'TCP', 'Specific Local Ports', enter '8085, 8086' in the text field
6. 'Allow the connection'
7. Choose zones where this rule applies
8. Enter the rule name and a description if desired

Done.